# given two state A and B of tower of hanoi, find out that is it possbile to reach from A to B moving optimally

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

Given two state A and B,find out that is it possible to reach B from A moving optimally.
where each state says the current position of disks in respective pegs. Here the number of pegs are 3.

### example

For N=3 disks and 3 pegs, the task is to move all the disk from peg 1 to 2 using peg 3

```
  peg(disk number)
```

state A - 1(4),  2(3,2,1), 3(blank)
explanation- peg one has disk no 4, peg 2 has disk no. 3,2,1 and peg 3 has disk no. 3
state B - 1(2,1), 2(blank), 3(4,3)

For the above case the answer is true, its possible to move.

### My current approach

For given N(no of disk),generate all the set put it in map, with generation time. For a given states compare the generation time and answer.

### Problem

For larger N=10^4 or more, its not feasible to generate all the set bcz total number of set is 2^N. I hope that a linear or logarithmic solution exist here.

Comment: Could you provide an example where one state isn't reachable from another? My intuition is that all states are reachable from any other, assuming the number of disks is the same.

Comment: Any state can be transformed to 1(N:1) 2(blank) 3(blank), so any state is reachable from any other state.